# Django's admin does not login after custom authentication

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-modeladmin

The custom authentication I wrote follows the instructions from [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/).  I am able to register, login, and logout the user, no problem there.  Then, when I create a superuser `python manage.py createsuperuser`, it creates a user in the database, but it does not let me login when I go to the admin page and try to login saying

> Please enter the correct email address and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.

Here is my code:

models.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, AbstractBaseUser, Group, Permission
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied, ObjectDoesNotExist, MultipleObjectsReturned
from datetime import datetime

from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin

import re

class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password = None):
        '''Creates and saves a user with the given email and password '''

        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Email address is requied.')
        user = self.model(email = self.normalize_email(email))
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        ''' Creates and saves a superuser with the given email and password '''
        user = self.create_user(email, password = password)
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user



class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
    Custom user class
    """

    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name = 'email address',unique = True, db_index = True)
    # email is the unique field that can be used for identification purposes

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    group = models.ManyToManyField(Group, related_name = 'users')
    permission = models.ManyToManyField(Permission, related_name = 'users')

    objects = CustomUserManager()


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'  # the unique identifier (mandatory)  The filed must have unique=True set in its definition (see above)


    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        ''' Does the user have a specific permission'''
        return True   # This may need to be changed depending on the object we want to find permission for

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        ''' Does the user have permission to view the app 'app_label'? The default answer is yes.
        This may be modified later on. '''

        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        ''' IS the user a member of staff? '''
        return self.is_admin



    def __unicode__(self):
        return '{user_email}, {user_title} joined on {joined_date}'.format(user_email = self.email,
                                                                       user_title = self.user_type,
                                                                       joined_date = self.joined)
```

In backends.py:

```
from django.conf import settings

from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password
from accounts.models import User

class EmailAuthBackend(object):
    ''' Custom authentication backend.  Allows users to login using their email address '''

    def authenticate(self, email=None, password = None):
        ''' the main method of the backend '''

        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email = email)

            if user.check_password(password):
                return user

        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(pk = user_id) # Note that you MUST use pk = user_id in getting the user.  Otherwise, it will fail and even though the user is authenticated, the user will not be logged in

            if user.is_active:
                return user
            return None
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

in admin.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField

from accounts.models import User as CustomUser


class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ''' A Form for creating new users. Includes all the required field, plus a repeated password.'''
    password1 = forms.CharField(label = 'Password', widget = forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label = 'Password Confirmation', widget = forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email',)

    def clean_password2(self):
        ''' Checks that the two password entries match '''
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')

        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords do NOT match!')
        return password2

    def save(self, commit = True):
        ''' Save the provided password in hashed format '''
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit = False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user

class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ''' A form for updating users. Includes all the field on the user, but replaces the password field with admin's password hash display field '''
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_active', 'is_admin')

        def clean_password(self):
            ''' Regardless of what the user provides, return the initial value.  This is done here rather than on the field because the field 
        does not have access to the initial value'''

            return self.initial['password']

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    ''' The form to add and change user instances '''
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm

    # The fields to be used in displaying the user model.
    # These override the defintions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User

    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_admin')
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal Info',{'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name',)}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin',)}),

        )
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute.  UserAdmin 
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user

    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2')}
            ),
    )

    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()

# Now, register the new UserAdmin...

admin.site.register(CustomUser, UserAdmin)

# ... and, since we're not using Django's built-in permissions,
# unregister the Group model from admin.
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

And, finally, in settings.py:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['accounts.backends.EmailAuthBackend',]
```

So what's missing?

Comment: Have you set the `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'` in the `settings.py`?

Comment: That's a lot of code... it would be better if you could narrow down where the problem is occurring. Are you sure the user exists in the database? Is the password hashed correctly in the database.

Comment: I don't think you need to define the `EmailAuthBackend`. The regular `ModelBackend` will handle `email` as the username since you have `USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'`. Try removing `EmailAuthBackend` and your  `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` setting in case the problem is there.

Comment: @Denis Olehov, I do have AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'

Comment: @Alasdair, the docs actually suggests to define a custom user model as a matter of best practice.  See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project). Also, I do believe you have to specify `USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'` in your model so that email is used to authenticate the user.

Comment: I didn't say that you shouldn't have a custom user model, and I didn't say that you shouldn't have `USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'`. I said that I don't think that you need `EmailAuthBackend` or `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` *because* you have `USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'`.

Comment: @Alasdair, thank you so much for your comment. Based on your suggestion, I commented out the `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` line in my settings.py file, and it paid off. It now lets me login.  So, the question is why putting my custom backend create the problem.  Also, when do I need a custom backend?  Say, if I wanted to add another authentication that lets users to login by their cell number rather than email, do I then have to add a custom backend?  In that case, what do I do that the Admin lets me in. I just want to understand the internal mechanism better.

Comment: I've explained a bit more in the answer below. Yes, if you want to authenticate with a field like `cell_number` that is not the username, then you could use a custom authentication backend for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is in your `EmailAuthBackend`. If you add some printing/logging to the backend, you'll find that [the login form calls the authenticate method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.10/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L190) with `username` and `password`. This means that `email` is `None`, and therefore the `user = User.objects.get(email = email)` lookup fails.

In your case, the regular `ModelBackend` will work fine for you, because you have `USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'`. If you remove `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` from your settings then the login should work. You can then remove your `EmailAuthBackend`.

If you wanted to log in users with their cell number and password (and `cell_number` was not the `USERNAME_FIELD`, then you *would* need a custom authentication backend. You would also need a custom authentication form that called `authenticate(cell_number=cell_number, password=password)`. Another example of a custom authentication backed is `RemoteUserBackend`, which logs in the user based on an environment variable set by the server.

Comment: So, do you mean that if my custom user model uses any field, say cell number, to log people in, as long as the USERNAME_FIELD of the model is set to that field, `USERNAME_FIELD = cell_number`, no custom backend is required?  And, that when I have a custom backend, I must also define a custom authentication form so that Django does not use its default authentication form? So, within my custom user model, I define a field called cell_number, and then define custom backend and authentication form to allow for authenticating using both email and cell_number. Correct?

Comment: Just about. The `ModelBackend` will handle login for `USERNAME_FIELD` and `password`, whether you've set `USERNAME_FIELD` to `username`, `email`, `cell_number` or something else. If you wanted to allow login with a different field, you would need a custom backend, and you would also need a custom form to pass the field value to your custom backend. You don't always need a custom authentication form for a custom authentication backend (e.g. `RemoteUserBackend` does not need a Django login form at all).

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Instead of `password=None`, I changed it to `password` only. And passed `'password=password'` , together with `'username=username'` as you can see below:

```
class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, password):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Please add an email address')
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Please add an username')

        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(
            email), username=username, password=password)

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
        user = self.create_user(email=self.normalize_email(
            email), username=username, password=password)
```

And as Denis has already said above, make sure to add `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'` to settings.py