# Django does not createing superuser with custom user model

Tags: django, django-models, django-1.11

I created a custom user model as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42093483/djangos-admin-does-not-login-after-custom-authentication) question. Only difference here is that I don't have a custom backend authentication.

I did the migration after creating the user model.

But `manage.py createsuperuser` not creating a super user in the db. I have created another user using registration form. The user is able to login and logout without any issue. So I manually changed `is_superuser` to True in db and I could login from the admin page.

What am I doing wrong here? Is it safe to create user from registration from and change to super user and use it?

I'm using django 1.11.13.

Comment: can you post the error? add some code of your model and if manager then manager too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment yet, hence the answer.

Without the code of your custom model and manager, it is hard to determine the error.

But I would suspect that your custom user model is missing correct manager.

I suggest you to look at the implementation of the Django user and UserManager in auth module to understand how this is done.

Comment: Issue got resolved. There was one line missing in the code, which is `user.save(using=self._db)`. Thank you for your time.